# Orthogonal projection with MySQL

Tags: mysql, gis

Is there an efficient way to calculate the orthogonal projection of a given point on a given Linestring with MySQL / MariaDB. (i.e. is there any smart work around as there does not seem to exist any built in function to do that natively)

Example:

Let's assume I want to project Point(1 1) on LINESTRING(0 0, 2 0), I am expecting to get Point(1 0) as the result

Also, I do know it is kind of trivial for PostgreSQL thanks to its built-in functions but I am asked to do it within MySQL (I do not mind using UDFs but I do not know C very well)

Comment: give a sample row, and the point of course. I assume you have looked at `ST_Line_Locate_Point()`

Comment: Actually ST_line_Locate_Point() is only for POSTGRES not  MySQL

Comment: are you going to show some table structures for mysql, or don't you care anymore ?

Comment: I do care. It is just that it is kind of a "generic" question and it was not obvious to me that it would require an example with tables. Just doing it for one point (assuming decent performance) is fine

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Is there an efficient way to calculate the orthogonal projection ...
>   with MySQL / MariaDB?

No. The MySQL geo extension doesn't support cartographic projections. PostgreSQL ... it does.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a "work around" knowing that it is not "built in" with MySQL.